# JOptionPane repeat Program by pressing a button

Tags: java, button, jlabel, joptionpane, repeat

I want to repeat my Program when you press the Button "Nochmal" (its german btw)
Everything works but i dont know the code to repeat the programm from the start.
btw its a random Number Generator with own input.

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;


public class randomNumberGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] options1 = { "Nochmal", "Quit" };

        int eingabe = Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Von 0 bis: ", null));

        Random rn = new Random();

        for(int i =0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            int answer =rn.nextInt(eingabe) + 1;

            JPanel antwort = new JPanel();
            antwort.add(new JLabel("Deine Zahl lautet: " + answer));

            int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, antwort, "RNG",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null, options1, null);
            if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
              //what to put into here?
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int i =0; i < 1; i++)` is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

just put :

```
 main(args);
```

You should get your logic out of the main method though.